# How to disable the form submit when input fields are incorrect in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I am checking for incorrect input with ng-pattern and showing error message on incorrect entry.

I want the form submit to be disabled when user tries to submit the form with incorrect values with out using `ng-disabled` option because `required` option of html is checking for empty text boxes on clicking submit button. How do I  achieve this? Do I have to go for custom directive?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Registratonvalidation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller("numOnlyRegex", function ($scope)
            {
                $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d{1,6}$/;
            });
        </script>
        <!--<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/numOnlyRegex.js"></script>-->
        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
                                <!--onSubmit="return validate()"-->
                                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="numOnlyRegex">
                                    <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate >
                                        First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span><br/>
                                        Last name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="lname" ng-model="lname" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-]{3,20}/" required placeholder="Last Name"/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.lname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span><br/>
                                        <p>Password:
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd" required placeholder="Password"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Confirm Password:<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd2" required placeholder="Confirm Password"/><br/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd2.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Gender: <input type="radio" name="female" ng-model="color" value="female" ng-required="!color"/>Female <input type="radio" name="male" ng-model="color" value="male" ng-required="!color"/>Male <br/><br/>
                                            Mobile:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="mobile" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{1,9}$/" ng-model="mobile" required placeholder="Mobile"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid mobile number</span><br/>
                                            Email:<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" ng-pattern="/\S+@\S+\.\S+/" ng-model="email" required placeholder="Email"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address</span><br/>
                                            Address:<textarea class="form-control input-sm" name="address" ng-model="address" required placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.address.$error.require==true">Address cannot be empty</span><br/>
                                            Street:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="street" ng-model="street" required placeholder="Street"/>
                                            Area:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="area" ng-model="area" required placeholder="Area"/>

                                            City:   <select name="city" class="form-control" ng-model="city" required>
                                                <option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                                                <option value="secunderabad">Secunderabad</option>
                                                <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
                                                <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                                            </select><br/>
                                            State: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="state" ng-model="state" required placeholder="State"/>
                                            Country: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="country" ng-model="country" required placeholder="Country"/>
                                            Pin:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-pattern="numOnlyRegex" name="pin" ng-model="pin" required placeholder="Pin"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pin.$error.pattern">Only six-digit number is allowed</span>
                                            <input type="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                                            <!--ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"-->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: May i know why you dont want to use ng-disabled ?

Comment: @kwan245 because when the user clicks on submit button it is checking for null inputs  and when I disable the submit button then how would the user know that he forgot a text box to be entered and end of the form on lets say on third page the button will be disabled and user might be thinking such a crappy form

Comment: so you will want to have [next button] to be disabled based on validation on each page -> before submit button ?

Comment: again the same scenario as the user will not know why the next button is disabled?

Comment: unless I show a message why the next button will be disabled but I don't want to show a static messages under input boxes telling the user to fill the text-boxes as it might just look ugly with all those messages

Comment: You can enable the [next] button first and do validation once user click next button -> next button always enabled but do validation before proceed it.

Comment: @kwan245 aha! Now you are at the point and how do I do that validation with out disabling the button is my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want all fields to be required, but that when users think they're ready for form submission, they are kindly notified if they have forgotten any required fields.

Normally this is achieved with ng-submit and something like:

```
<span ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.formField.$error.required">Please enter information for 'formField'</span>
```

Here the users are allowed to click submit, but are then shown a message about the required field.

However, this is only works when no action (`action="RegistrationServlet.do"`) is specified on the form. In your case, you need to intercept form submission. One way to do that is to capture the mouse click event to disable and update the form if there are form errors:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function($event) {
  if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
     $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
     $event.preventDefault();    
  }
}

<form name="myForm" action="action.do" method="Post" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="formField" ng-model="formField" required><br>
  <span class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.formField.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[See the plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jeHeVB?p=preview)

Comment: Exactly this is what I want. I hope this works with my form as I have action servlet and also ng-pattern validation inline in tags. Let me try and I will update you if its working. Thanks @p65537

Comment: When I do this, the validation on input fields are not working

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation#disabling-the-submit-button-ng-disabled) will help explain how to disable a submit button until a form is valid.

You will need to add `ng-disabled="FORMNAME.$invalid"` attribute to your `<input type="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Submit" />` element (replace FORMNAME with the model name for your form data).

That should do it. Comment below with any other issues.

Comment: I don't want to use `ng-disabled` as I have mentioned in the question because the submit button is checking for null inputs

Comment: so you want to allow null input then why it is listed as required ?

Comment: I don't want null inputs. Think it as a real time form and try it in plunker you   will get an idea

Comment: `ng-disabled="FORMNAME.$invalid"` does much more than looking for `null` inputs. It also checks the `type` of each element to match the REGEX for that type (such as `type="tel" for telephone #'s).

Comment: I don't think `ng-disabled="FORMNAME.$invalid"` will check for null input, It just disables the form until user fills in all the `required` values

Comment: `$invalid` checks the REGEX values stored in the Angular library against the input field's `type`/

Comment: `$invalid` checks a form against REGEX values that Angular has stored in its source code for the `type` attribute in a form element. I also created a plunkr that seems to work with `ng-disabled`. Can you point out what is wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/7CdUdW4g1qlqRiq6DtQ0?p=preview

Comment: Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zr6buJARsGezt6508TAR?p=preview  where I have used `ng-disabled` which is not checking for input values

Comment: When I test your custom validations on that plunkr, `ng-disabled` works as intended. I am lost as to what problem you are running into.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is using ng-Submit so that you can do validation when user click submit.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('numOnlyRegex',function($scope){
 $scope.TestSubmit = function()
 {
   if($scope.myForm.$valid)
   {
     //normal submit
   }
 }

});
```

Updated base on you plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/FypBs8IiHmPKJYrsR1xJ?p=preview